# Converting between right-handed cartesian coordinates and upside-down y-coordinate system.

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

I've been looking into a solution to this issue for over a day now and haven't managed to find a possible calculation, matrix calculation or similar that can possibly convert between these two systems.

To clarify further I have the following examples, the black circles highlight the corner for the nearest listed x-y coordinates:

Right-hand cartesian system and example object placement with origins:

[image: Righthand cartesian system]

[image: Cartesian Righthanded - Bottom Left Origin]

upside-down y-coordinate system with new object placement origins:

[image: upside-down y-coordinate system]

[image: upside-down y-coordinate system. - Top Left Origin]

The origin has changed from bottom-left to top-left and the Y-axis is now upside down.

Are there any know approaches that can convert between these two formats? The second example shows the conversion from the first image, what I'm looking to find out is how/if it's possible to calculate the conversion between these systems.

Comment: the objects (walls in this example) are 200 thick. the space between the wall on the X axis is 5000. 3000 on the Y axis. The round highlights are the 'origin' corners for each rectangular 'wall' object.

Comment: Ah, okay. One has to be quite careful when interpreting the pictures. But what exactly are the coordinates on the second picture? Are they still the coordinates of the four black circles?

Comment: Yes the coords represent the nearest corner highlighted by a black circle (sorry for the lack of clarity there). The main question here is how it's possible to convert between the origin points in the first picture and those in the second. The altered origins (bottom-left to top-left) and the upside-down Y-axis are giving me quite a headache.

Comment: Can you identify which origin point in the first picture corresponds to which object?

Comment: What's your algorithm for drawing the object once you have an origin point and a width and length?

Comment: The origin point for the first system (right-handed cartesian) is always bottom-left. That for the second (right-handed cartesian with upside-down Y) is always top-left.

The rectangular objects here are placed manually by drawing, the issue is that although I have the base format and converted result, I do not have a clue how that conversion can be calculated reliably, in the end, this will be programmed into a C# application but for now, I'm attempting to work out the conversion logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it easier for you by changing your original diagram a little:

[image]

Now you should be able to see what the corresponding points are:

Working clockwise from the top left,

$x_1=0, y_1=3400$ maps to $x_2=0, y_2=-200$

$x_1=5200, y_1=3200$ maps to $x_2=5200, y_2=0$

$x_1=5000, y_1=0$ maps to $x_2=5000, y_2=3200$

$x_1=-200, y_1=200$ maps to $x_2=-200, y_2=3000$

It should now be obvious that the relationship between the coordinates is:

$$x_2=x_1$$

$$y_2=3200-y_1$$

Comment: Thanks again, i really appreciate your effort! My main issue though is how can i generically work out the mapping between the original origin points and x1/y1? The rotation is what throws me off. Past the origin mapping it's...as you've said, pretty obvious. it's just that damn origin mapping that confuses me.

Comment: It's not actually a rotation, but a reflection. The $x$ values are unaltered. I don't really understand what you're struggling with. I've given you a way to convert the original values $(x_1, y_1)$ to new values $(x_2, y_2)$.

Comment: Most of the struggle was a lack of sleep :P That helped me perfectly and the conversion logic is fully implimented. Many thanks!